# Exception on traveling through pixels BMP C#

Tags: c#

Im using the following code to travel though the pixels of a BMP as this

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Image.Width; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j <= Image.Height; j++)
    {
              color = Image.GetPixel(i, j); //get 
    }

 }
```

but im getting a exception

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message="Parameter must be positive and < Height.\r\nParameter name: y"
  Source="System.Drawing"
  ParamName="y"
```

I have no clue why im getting this.. im using a `BMP` with valid heights and same code with hard-coded values working correctly

@Odded

No:1 Shows what i needed  and no 2 is whats happening with ur code any idea?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear enough if the answers below did not help.

Comment: I have a feeling you're copying one image into another image of a different width and height. If this is the case, it's not clear in your question at all.

Comment: If you still have the issue, first use X and Y instead of I and J (easier to avoid confusion between vertical and horizontal), then check everywhere in your code that: inner loops are always corresponding to the width: for(int x = 0; x < BMP.Width; ++x), and Get/SetPixels calls always use X and Y in that order.

Comment: Cant understand what you are trying to get here.  Even with the pictures I have no clue..  Please reword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change Height and Width. This is such an example of looking too far in your own code - this brings back so many memories..

```
for(int i=0;i<BMP.Height;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<BMP.Width;j++)
   {
      color = BMP.GetPixel(j,i);    
   }
}
```

Comment: This will try to access `GetPixel(Height-1, Width-1)`, which DOES NOT EXIST and will cause an exception.  Don't understand how this ever got any upvotes, nevermind the most.

Comment: @Uw: The (first) downvote came from me, since your answer is wrong.

Comment: I am so pro-constructive comments. Thank you Ben, I will edit my post.

Comment: Hi the problem is not solved yet :-( .. same thing happen vertically now not reading row by row of image

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the problem is now ?

Comment: can you either provide more code, or can you debug both `Width` and `Height` value and see if those are the same as the expected values ?

Comment: are you clear abut my prob >? :-) its doesnt go line by line of pixels just going aas sets in the image

Comment: @Sudantha: if it works with hard-coded values, then something must be different with the `BMP.Height` and `BMP.Width`. Well, at least, that's what one would think.

Answer (score 5):

You have an off-by-one error in your loops.

If the image `Height` and `Width` is 100, to get the "last" pixel you will need to call it as `GetPixel(99,99)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Image.Width; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < Image.Height; j++)
    {
              color = Image.GetPixel(i, j); //get 
    }

 }
```

Comment: I think u will be fine giving the 'accepted answer' to a newbie as a motivation :-)

Comment: Oded i hace a small prob ... this way pixels are not traveled from line by line

Comment: @Sudantha - That's how you wrote the code. What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Sudantha - You need to switch the `Image.Width` with `Image.Height` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

Swap the two loops.

```
for(int j=0; j<BMP.Height; j++)
{
   for(int i=0; i<BMP.Width; i++)
   {
      color = BMP.GetPixel(i,j);     
   }
}
```

Everyone is focusing on width and height, that's NOT the solution.  `GetPixel` takes two arguments, `x` and `y`.  The `y` coordinate must be the outer loop to get the order you want.

The x-coordinate always runs from `0` ... `Width-1`

Comment: I can see there is no condition in your first for loop. I believe this will throw an exception.

Comment: `for(x;y;z)` y has to be boolean `BMP.Height` is not.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer. Most others are wrong because i and j in GetPixel(i,j) must correspond to Width and Height, respectively. (Just a remaining typo, "j<BMP.Height" is missing the "j<", as in the question code)

Comment: Yeah, yeah, there was a typo.  Do you notice that the question contained the same typo?  Do you notice that your own answer, @Bala, contains the same typo?

Comment: @Ben I noticed that but I was going to delete my answer so didn't care to fix but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Hi the problem is not solved yet :-( .. same thing happen vertically now not reading row by row of image

Answer (score 1):

Flip your loops around.  The outer loop should be the height and the inner loop should be the width if you want it to behave like the 1st image.

Comment: Hi the problem is not solved yet :-( .. same thing happen vertically now not reading row by row of image

Answer (score 1):

Just swap around the Width and Height:

```
for(int i=0;i<BMP.Height;i++){

   for(int j=0;j<BMP.Width;j++){
      color=BMP.GetPixel(j, i);
   }
}
```

I've also swapped around `i` and `j` so that `GetPixel` works correctly

Comment: Hi the problem is not solved yet :-( .. same thing happen vertically now not reading row by row of image

Answer (score 1):

Let's make this simple and use x and y instead of i and j so it's easier to think about in Cartesian coordinates.

```
//For each height, loop through all pixels at that height.
for(int y=0; y < BMP.Height; y++)
{
    for(int x=0; x < BMP.Width; x++)
    {
        color = BMP.GetPixel(x,y);     
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks Joe just check i have a another problem adressing with this check the bottom of the question