# Pixel travelling problem in BMP C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception on traveling through pixels BMP C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054486/exception-on-traveling-through-pixels-bmp-c)

I have `BMP` image and used two loops to access its pixels

```
for(int i=0;i<BMP.Width;i++){

   for(int j=0;BMP.Height;j++){

      color=BMP.GetPixel(i,j);     

   }

}
```

My problem is using the above loops pixels are readed like 2nd in the bottom image but what im required is as 1st image

[image]

This what happening now

[image]